# Intent not available from within app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the intent `com.amazon.tv.settings/.hud.HudActivity` which I can launch through adb using `adb shell am start -n "com.amazon.tv.settings/.hud.HudActivity"` on the Amazon Fire TV v3.
However when I launch the same intent through code:

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(new Intent("com.amazon.tv.settings/.hud.HudActivity"));
```

It is unable to find the activity producing the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
                  Process: com.baronkiko.launcherhijack, PID: 23262
                  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.amazon.tv.settings/.hud.HudActivity }
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:820)
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:797)
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:356)
                      at com.baronkiko.launcherhijack.AccServ$1.run(AccServ.java:111)
                      at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
                      at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

This is a system intent that I really need. How can I launch this intent, do I need some more permissions?
I appreciate any help I may receive.

Comment: Is HudActivity declared in your manifest file? And intent usually take in two parameters, like new Intent(Context,Class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.amazon.tv.settings", "com.amazon.tv.settings.hud.HudActivity"));
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

When you call

```
new Intent("com.amazon.tv.settings/.hud.HudActivity")
```

"com.amazon.tv.settings/.hud.HudActivity" is regarded as action not class name.

Comment: It definitely finds the package and tries to launch it. I now get a permissions error as it wants "android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" to open it.  Not sure why but I am trying to grant said permission from the ADB shell which is proving tougher that thought as this is an unrooted device. Any idea why this perm is needed? And how to grant it for that matter.

Comment: Please go to the class HudActivity to find more details or think more about your needs.

Comment: Sadly I have no control over HudActivity, nor any documentation regarding it. It's an in built part of the FireTV, the long press menu.
I have no choice but to launch this intent :(

Comment: Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to create appropriate Intent:

```
getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.amazon.tv.settings/.hud.HudActivity");
```

Comment: I like how neat this is but I kept getting null reference exceptions. Probably because I was calling it from within a timer delegate. While I could probably fix it Q Lockers solution works in place aside from permission issues. Thanks for your help.